# How to add an additional temporary IP to the connection that currently provides internet via nmcli?

Tags: nmcli, ip-address

I need to add a specific IP to the interface that actively provides the internet connection, like so:

```
network_dev=$(nmcli --get-values DEVICE connection show --active | grep w)
sudo ip a add 192.168.250.9/24 dev $network_dev
```

This address assignment should be temporary and should not be applied between `nmcli c up/down id "My connection"`

Is there a way to perform this operation directly through `nmcli`?

Comment: If you're only adding an address temporarily, why not just use `ip addr add`?

Comment: It seems more convenient to perform this operation through `nmcli` so that I could easily add `nmcli` command to the `/etc/sudoers` file in order to let the user execute it without sudo password (useful for unattended scripts with reconnection functionality).